# Bundle over $\mathbb CP^\infty$

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, complex-geometry, vector-bundles

Good time of day. I have the following question

Let $\eta$ -tautological bundle over $\mathbb CP^\infty$. I don't understand why there is no such complex vector bundle $\xi$ over $\mathbb CP^\infty$ that bundle $\eta \bigoplus  \xi$ is trivial.

I'm not sure about my attempt. I try to use Pontryagin classes for solving this task. If these classes are non-vanishing then this bundle will be non-trivial.

We know that $2p(E \bigoplus F)=2p(E)\smile p(F)$

and it's famous fact that if $\theta$ is oriented real bundle of rank $2k$ then $p_k(\theta)=e(\theta)^2$, where $e(\theta)^2$ is the square of Euler class.

I don't know how to continue and compute this

Thank you for your help

Comment: Given that these bundles are complex vector bundles, I would suggest using Chern classes instead. Are you familiar with them?

Comment: @Michael Albanese. Yes, I'm familiar with them a bit. As I understand these Chern classes should be also non-vanishing for non-triviality of this bundle $\eta \bigoplus \xi$? Am I correct?

Comment: That's not necessarily true. It is possible to have a non-trivial bundle with trivial Chern classes. Instead, try contradiction. Suppose such a $\zeta$ exists. What can you say about its Chern classes?

Comment: @Michael Albanese I know that the first Chern class of a trivial bundle is zero.

Comment: So $c_1(\eta\oplus\zeta) = 0$. What does this tell you about $c_1(\eta)$ and $c_1(\zeta)$?

Comment: @Michael Albanese One of them is zero since $c_1(\eta \bigoplus \xi)=c_1(\eta)c_1(\xi)$ from the Whitney sum formula

Comment: You've made a common mistake. The *total* Chern class satisfies $c(\eta\oplus\zeta) = c(\eta)c(\zeta)$, but the first Chern class satisfies $c_1(\eta\oplus\zeta) = c_1(\eta)+c_1(\zeta)$.

Comment: @Michael Albanese thank you for your help

Comment: Were you able to solve the problem? If so, you can write your solution as an answer to this question so that it does not remain unanswered.

Comment: @Michael Albanese. I try to compute the first chern class of tautological bundle $\eta$ over $CP^\infty$ and I don't know hot to compute  this, can you help please with this last step? I have computed the first Chern class for complex vector bundle. I'm not sure but it is equal to n-fold product of $c_1(\xi)=\alpha$ where $\alpha$ is a generator of $H^{*}(CP^\infty; Z)$ (since we have n-dimensional complex vector bundle)

Comment: You can express the Chern classes of $\zeta$ in terms of the Chern classes of $\eta$. For the first Chern class, we have $0 = c_1(\eta\oplus\zeta) = c_1(\eta) + c_1(\zeta)$, so $c_1(\zeta) = -c_1(\eta)$. What do you get for $c_2(\zeta)$?

Comment: @Michael Albanese. Possibly $c_2(\xi)=e$, where e is Euler class $\in$ $H^{2k}(CP^\infty)$.

Comment: @Michael Albanese if you don't mind may you please describe last steps in more details? About the second Chern class of tautological bundle $\eta$. As I understand this is equal to $(1+c_1(\xi))(1+c_1(\xi))$ but I'm not sure. Thank you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134951/discussion-between-michael-albanese-and-usere).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Michael Albanese the following method based on Chern classes to me.

Suppose that a complex vector bundle $\zeta$ exists such that $\eta \oplus \zeta$ is trivial. We have known that the first Chern classes for trivial bundles vanish, i.e. $c_1(\eta\oplus\zeta) = 0$.

It follows that $c_1(\eta\oplus\zeta) = c_1(\eta)+c_1(\zeta)=0$, so $c_1(\zeta)=-c_1(\eta)$.

We have expressed the first Chern class of $\zeta$ in terms of the Chern classes of $\eta$. We will continue to do the same for higher Chern classes.

Since we the tautological bundle over $\mathbb CP^\infty$ is a complex line bundle we have $c_2(\eta) = 0$. Also we have $c_2(\eta\oplus\zeta) = 0$ since we assumed that bundle $\eta\oplus\zeta$ is trivial. Therefore

$$0 = c_2(\eta\oplus\zeta) = c_2(\eta) + c_1(\eta)c_1(\zeta) + c_2(\zeta) = 0 + c_1(\eta)(-c_1(\eta)) + c_2(\zeta),$$

so $c_2(\zeta) = c_1(\eta)^2$.

Likewise $c_3(\eta\oplus\zeta)=c_3(\eta)+c_1(\eta)c_2(\zeta)+c_1(\zeta)c_2(\eta)+c_3(\zeta)=0$, and we see that  $c_3(\zeta)=-c_1(\eta)^3$.

Also $c_4(\zeta)=c_4(\eta)+c_2(\eta)c_2(\zeta)+ c_1(\eta)c_3(\zeta)+c_3(\eta)c_1(\zeta)+c_4(\zeta)=0$, so $c_4(\zeta)=c_1(\eta)^4$.

One can see that the $k^{\text{th}}$ Chern class satisfies $c_k(\zeta)=(-1)^k c_1(\eta)^k$.

Combining the famous fact from the theory of fiber bundles that for a vector bundle of rank $k$, all Chern classes for $i > k$ are vanishing
and the results of our computations showing that $c_i(\zeta) = (-1)^ic_1(\eta)^i \neq 0$ we have obtained a contradiction.

In summary, one can see from the triviality of the bundle $\eta \oplus \zeta$ that $c(\eta\oplus\zeta) = 1 \implies c_i(\zeta) = (-1)^ic_1(\eta)^i \neq 0$ for every $i$. This is impossible since the Chern classes of $\zeta$ should vanish above its rank.

Comment: I hope you don't mind, I edited your answer to clean it up a bit. Just a couple of comments. First, you can prove that $c_k(\zeta) = (-1)^kc_1(\eta)^k$ by induction. Second, the fact that $c_i(\zeta) \neq 0$ requires one to know that $c_1(\eta)^i \neq 0$. This is the case because $c_1(\eta) \in H^2(\mathbb{CP}^{\infty}; \mathbb{Z})$ is non-zero and $H^*(\mathbb{CP}^{\infty}; \mathbb{Z}) \cong \mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ where $\deg\alpha = 2$.